# How to redo an undo that deleted an object?

Tags: modeling

I was working on a project that took a long time. I have two meshes, one I put a lot of time in. I joined the two meshes together, and worked a bit on them, but then decided I wanted to disjoin them. Upon hitting Ctrl+Z, one of my meshes dissappeared. I tried redoing using Ctrl+Shft+Z but that didnt work. I tried recovering from autosave, but that failed too. I tried closing it and reopening it, but that didnt work either.

Is my mesh completely gone forever? :(

Comment: I think no one can't tell better what's going on in your file except for you. The mesh couldn't just *dissappear* even if it seemed like that. Keep checking what's going on in your scene with Outliner. As it's stated now it seems there were modifiers on mesh which probably caused some unexpected behaviour after unjoining or you moved new object either to another layer or you were in Local view. Provide [your blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) to hopefully get more detailed answer; make sure to delete unneded parts to decrease its size.

Comment: Sounds like trouble with "object mode undo stack" and "edit mode" undo stack, the user probably joined the meshes into one object entered edit mode and and then used undo, and somehow Blender was unable to recreate the original object before being joined. Not sure though, just my guess. Sad part is, if you saved your file or already closed and reopened Blender it is probably gone for good. Try unhiding everything with Alt+H or opening one of the backup .blend1 files and see if it still there, but I wouldn't expect much luck with it. For the future try saving your file as more often.